# How to implement a delegate control for only the mysites?

Tags: master-page, my-site, delegate-control

I created a delegate control and it works fine. I add it to the `AdditionalPageHead`. Now it is visible on all Master Pages. I would like to make it only visible on the `My Sites`. How to do this without modifying the Master Page?

Comment: Have you consider an idea for having separate master pages for My sites?